# Display custom blocks in magento error

Tags: php, magento, block

I am trying to do custom blocks in magento, for that i have created a cms page called Testpage, and inside the URL Key, i have given c-integration i think this seems to be block id, and status is enabled, inside the content text box i gave a short code like this

> {{block type="core/template" template=”syt/syt_home.phtml”}}

In my syt_home.phtml i have given an echo statement, but this is not coming in the front end, i am not sure what i did wrong? also changed the cms home page to cms Testpage in admin side.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the block appears in that cms page by enabling the template path hint. If the block presents in that page but the content is not displaying than either there is a problem in the folder structure or in the code inside the phtml file.Is the folder **syt** is inside the template directory of your theme? This can be one of the reason.

> Updated check the code {{block type="core/template"
>   template="page/html/home.phtml"}}. this is the way to give the path. Inside the template directory of your theme create the folder structure as you wish and place it inside that folder .You can follow as in above example.

By checking this you can narrow down the problem. Hope this will help.

Comment: syt is my custom package name, but this is not inside the template dir, template dir is inside the syt theme.

Comment: i have updated the answer please try that. Hope that should work for you.

Comment: i have changed the syt_home.phtml to c_home.phtml {{block type="core/template" template="syt/c_home.phtml"}} now it is worked, Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom blocks can be a very tricky thing in Magento.

Try this guide. I've found it to be extremely helpful.

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/